# AWS Zeppelin notebok server JDBC access denied

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, amazon-ec2, aws-glue

When I run AWS Glue Zeppelin notebook server I got this error:

```
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not open SSL root certificate file /home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem (Permission denied)
```

So I run the following:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/ec2-user/glue-files/
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

After that the rights are shown as follows

```
                                                      rights    owner
/home/ec2-user/glue-files                             rwxrwxrwx root                         
/home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem  rw-rw-rw- root
```

But the same error persists. Any input as to how to fix it?

Tried this

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem 

                                                      rights    owner
/home/ec2-user/glue-files/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem  rwxr-xr-x root
```

Still the same error.